# Truncation/removing of the last 5% of the distance data

Tags: r

In order for my reasearch to work i need to truncate/remove the larges distances from my dataset. The truncation is 5% of the distance set. So i need to remove the largest 5% distances from my dataset.

I visualised this 5% as the 95% quantile with:
`quantile(TD2S1WP$distance,c(.95),na.rm = TRUE)`
and this gave the result:
95%
41.8

So if i am correct all distances of 41.8 and higher are the 5% of the data i need to truncate/remove from my dataset.

I tried doing this with:
TD2S1WP.2 <- TD2S1WP[!(TD2S1WP$distance>41.8),]

But when i look at the new datset the 41.8 distances and higher were still present in the dataset.

So my question is. how to i remove the larges 5% of my distance data from my dataset?

This is my dataset.

```
> dput(TD2S1WP)
structure(list(Region.Label = c("TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", 
"TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", 
"TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", 
"TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", 
"TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", 
"TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", 
"TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", 
"TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1", "TD2S1"), Area = c(462, 462, 
462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 
462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 
462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 
462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 462, 462), Sample.Label = 
c("11", 
"11", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "12", "12", "12", "12", 
"12", "3", "3", "3", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "4", "9", 
"9", "9", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
"8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "14", "14", "2", "13", "13", 
"1", "7", "15"), Effort = c(0.341, 0.341, 0.326, 0.326, 0.326, 
0.326, 0.326, 0.326, 0.326, 0.308, 0.308, 0.308, 0.308, 0.308, 
0.311, 0.311, 0.311, 0.315, 0.315, 0.315, 0.315, 0.315, 0.315, 
0.303, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.324, 0.324, 0.324, 0.324, 0.324, 0.324, 
0.324, 0.324, 0.324, 0.325, 0.325, 0.325, 0.325, 0.325, 0.325, 
0.325, 0.333, 0.333, 0.343, 0.318, 0.318, 0.322, 0.346, 0.312
), distance = c(0.6, 0.6, 21, 21, 7, 6.3, 16, 1.4, 1.4, 0.5, 
0.5, 1.4, 19, 4.8, 0.5, 0.5, 13, 41.8, 41.8, 41.8, 41.8, 41.8, 
41.8, 16.6, 8.5, 0.3, 8.6, 10.3, 10.3, 10.3, 10.3, 13.1, 13.1, 
13.1, 13.1, 13.1, 1.6, 1.6, 1, 2.3, 2.3, 14.1, 0.3, 7.7, 3.4, 
27, 16, 15.6, 21.3, NA, NA), Study.Area = c("TownDistrict2", 
"TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", 
"TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", 
"TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", 
"TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", 
"TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", 
"TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", 
"TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", 
"TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", 
"TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", 
"TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", 
"TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", 
"TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2", 
"TownDistrict2", "TownDistrict2")), row.names = c(NA, -51L), class = 
c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead: `TD2S1WP.2 <- TD2S1WP[TD2S1WP$distance < 41.8,]` to keep rows below the threshold. I think the issue that you are asking R to remove rows greater than 41.8 not greater than or equal to. It seems easier to use < operator.

For keeping NA values:

```
TD2S1WP.2 <- TD2S1WP[TD2S1WP$distance < 41.8 | is.na(data$distance),]
```

Comment: Hi, the distance data is continous and I need the largest 5% of my distances removed.
The example above did not seem to work. But i included the dput() data which might help?

Comment: Try the code above, it works fine on my system. I think it may just be choice of equality operator that is causing the issue.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that the code works but now it is causing another issue. WHen running the code it truncates 5% of the data. But in my dataseet i have some data where a survey was done with no observations, so no distances, and these were deleted as well.

Comment: If you want to keep the NA values then see updated answer, you can use | to add an or condition and is.na() to tell it to keep distance under 41.8 or NA values